# Need help on Linear Algebra Done Right problem on linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Exercises 3B Q2:

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$ are such that 
$$\text{range }S \subset \text{null }T$$
Prove $(ST)^2 = 0$

I found the solution [here](http://linearalgebras.com/3b.html). I understand the solution, but I think of something different when I try the question by myself and want to know any mistake I have made.

When I saw $\text{range }S \subset \text{null }T$, my thought was the dimension of $\text{range }S \leq $  the dimension of $\text{null }T$. **I am not sure whether this is correct.**

If this is correct, then
$$(ST)^2 = S(T(S(T(u))))$$
Let's look at $T(S(T(u))$, **not sure whether this is correct again**
$$\text{dim }S(T(u)) =\text{dim range }T + \text{dim null }T$$
$$\text{dim range }S =\text{dim range }T + \text{dim null }T$$

Because $\text{dim range }S \leq \text{dim null }T$, dim range $T$ must be equal to zero, and $\text{dim range }S = \text{dim null }T$
*because dim range S cannot be smaller than dim null T*
**Not sure whether this is correct again**

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean by $dim(S(T(u))$. The rank-nullity theorem says that $dim(V)=dim(Ker(T))+dim(Range(T))$. The property you need to prove follows from the fact that you "feed" $T$ by elements in the range of $S$, which is contained in its kernel. That is, $T(S(u))=0$ for any $u$,

Comment: @GReyes My though was:
$u \in V$, $T(u) \in V$, then we can put that into $S$, so $S(T(u))$. And this is the range of $S$?

And consider the linear map $T(S(T(u)))$, the dim $S(T(u)) = \text{dim range }T + \text{dim null }T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using matrix notation if the range of $S$ is in the nullspace of $T$ then $TS$ is zero and so $(ST)^2=(ST)(ST)=S(TS)T=0$ which is the result.